# Installing pyglpk package on Windows10

Tags: python, pip, installation, glpk

I don't have much knowledge for technical details of installing packages, etc, so this might be a stupid question. I simply first downloaded GLPK and added it to the path, and then tried to install pyglpk through `pip install glpk`, which gives the following error messages:

```
Collecting glpk
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/e0/8676d8d5404a8f9aee298985d21aae67b776476b01583ff1a3e0030e2f51/glpk-0.4.5.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: glpk
  Building wheel for glpk (PEP 517) ... error
  ERROR: Complete output from command 'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpzvxrzwqg':
  ERROR: running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  building 'glpk' extension
  creating build
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DVERSION_NUMBER="0.4.5" -IC:\Users\User\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Users\User\Anaconda3\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc\glpk.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\src\glpk.obj
  glpk.c
  c:\users\user\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-m71t9t2y\glpk\src\lp.h(24): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'glpk.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for glpk
  Running setup.py clean for glpk
Failed to build glpk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for glpk which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

I tried to search for different installation tutorials or questions online, but most of them are for Linux/MacOS, but not for Windows. What can I do about this?

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Windows

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+open+include+file%3A+%27glpk.h%27%3A+No+such+file+or+directory

Comment: The link seems to be for installing GLPK in Windows, which I already succeeded in doing, but it's the Python package installation I'm stuck at.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLPK/Python

Comment: Thank you. I also tried that, but in Windows there is no command of `sudo make install`, so I'm lost here. What command should be used in Windows instead?

Comment: http://tfinley.net/software/pyglpk/building.html *Perhaps you do not actually have a glpk.h file in the include directories. This may be because you have a binary non-developer installation of GLPK.*

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to run glpk in python without using PIP. I get the same issue and couldn't solve it with PIP.

First thing is download GLPK solver:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/winglpk/
GLPK is based in C. You must check where is a file called glpsol.exe 
And add that directory to the path.
[look remarked txt in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YK19.png)

After that you can run your pyomo model and select GLPK as your solver.

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for `glpk.h` in the folder `C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\include`.  You can make the installation succeed by copying `glpk.h` from the GLPK installation into that folder.  You will also need to copy `glpk.lib` into `C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\libs`.