# Error while installing glpk on windows 10 64-bit Python 3.9 VBS 2022

Tags: python-3.x, pip, runtime-error, python-wheel, glpk

```
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\Sem3\Codes\Possibly_smart> pip install glpk
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting glpk
  Using cached glpk-0.4.7.tar.gz (161 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: glpk
  Building wheel for glpk (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for glpk (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'glpk' extension
      creating build
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\src
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DVERSION_NUMBER=\"\\\"0.4.7\\\"\" "-IC
:\Program Files\Python39\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python39\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x
86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program File
s (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-
IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.
8\include\um" /Tcsrc\2to3.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\src\2to3.obj
      2to3.c
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DVERSION_NUMBER=\"\\\"0.4.7\\\"\" "-IC
:\Program Files\Python39\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Python39\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x
86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program File
s (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-
IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.
8\include\um" /Tcsrc\bar.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\src\bar.obj
      bar.c
      C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vi2p8jp3\glpk_61c8cc901091414192986f371950762c\src\lp.h(24): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'glpk.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for glpk
Failed to build glpk
ERROR: Could not build wheels for glpk, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Apparently the header file glpk.h is missing or the compiler can't find it. I'm using Windows 10 64-bit, Visual Basic tools 2022, Pycharm, Python 3.9 and have virtually tired every thing form downloading tar file to upgrading various libraries and even python.
Nothing seems to work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62265589/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glpk+pip

Comment: This did not work. However I was able to build the glpk by copying it to path in both user and system variables in adv windows settings.